# How to uninstall multiple Bower packages like in Composer?

Tags: composer-php, bower

I'm just starting to use Bower, and it's really useful, but one thing I don't understand how to do is something similar to Composer: updating/deleting your dependencies based on the json file.

So, in composer, if I have something like:

```
 "require": {   
        ...
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^2.3",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^2.3.8",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3"
    },
```

And if I delete one dependency's line(or more) and run

> composer update

This will not only update any of the outdated dependencies, but also delete the folders corresponding to the deleted dependencies.

How can I achieve the same in Bower? Is there a similar command or combinations of commands, eventually?

I've tried

> bower update

But that just updades the dependencies.

I've also tried

> bower uninstall "dependency"

But this works only for one, and doesn't automatically detect what I have and what I don't, like in Composer's case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is

```
bower prune
```

You can also do

```
bower uninstall package1 package2 --save --save-dev
```

Comment: Hm, you're right. Unfortunately I have to run `bower update` afterwards, so that's two commands. The second example that you gave is not really what I'm looking for, because I have to manually say what I want uninstalled.

Comment: Yes, that's how npm and bower differ from composer. You can make a shortcut for `bower prune && bower update` with npm script or batch/shell.

Comment: Well only thing I know about node is how to install packages, but I will look into that.